# Controlling a CLI program with Python

Tags: python, shell, powershell, command-line, automation

I'm using Python 3.5 and I'd like to run a program that is normally run within cmd.exe or powershell.  This program is not in the environment PATH, and I'd like to avoid adding it.

I need to start the program and then just pass two or three word commands within the program.

I've looked on Stack Exchange and Google, but many things are references on how to launch a script with Powershell.  I need to issue commands one-by-one because the commmand timings are relevent to other parts of the application (other things in the program need to happen in a serial manner).

I've tried to get `subprocess.call` to work, but I can't get it to launch the program...Same with `os.system`.

PyWinAuto won't launch the program in it's own window, but rather just the console, so that's out....Plus, I can't get PyWinAuto to recognize that it should use the `SendKeys()` method on said console anyway.

I'd like to launch:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever.exe
```

Then, when it launches, start sending in things like

```
command 1 argument 1 argument 2 <enter>
command 2 argument 1 argument 2 <enter>
command 3 argument 1 argument 2 <enter>
```

Comment: Pywinauto is for GUI, not for CLI. You need to use `subprocess.Popen` and stdin/stdout/stderr pipes. Just read the docs about `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the experimental support for Windows that was recently added to the pexpect package:

http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#windows

If that doesn't meed your needs, the winpexpect package looks interesting, although I haven't used it myself:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/winpexpect

https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home